# No RAID Controller on UCS C220

Tags: raid, storage, cisco-ucs

Is it possible to not use any kind of RAID Controller on a Cisco UCS, if I want to use just one HDD without RAID features ? Or do I have to still have the RAID hardware controller to create my disk as a JBOD ?

Thank you

Comment: IMHO most people value their data and reliability above the purchasing price of a second disk. -|- Regardless do you already have your server? In that case: **which RAID controller** option is installed and which OS will you be running?  -|- If you're only considering purchasing, ask you sales rep, he both gets paid for answering those questions and might give you a quote (different from the list price) for each of the options you're deliberating, allowing an informed choice.

Comment: I already have the server, and the RAID controller is ordered but I have to start production on this server without it because of time constraints. So I'm looking at my options. OS will be Win2k8 R2. I don't know what you mean by RAID controller option though...

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/c/hw/C220/install/C220/raid.html lists a number of different supported RAID controllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/c/hw/C220/install/C220/raid.html lists a number of different optional RAID controllers but also explains that such a server also always has an embedded MegaRAID software RAID controller.

You can disable the onboard software RAID controller from the BIOS, it then behaves as a normal SATA/SAS controller.

So yes you can place a single disk and install your OS and start running with a single disk.

That document also explains that you can't upgrade from the on-board software raid controller to a hardware controller and keep your data.